# Is Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) a parametric approach?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

There are to main probabilistic approaches to novelty detection: parametric and non-parametric. Non-para assumes the distribution or density function derived from the training data, like Kernel Density Estimation (e.g.:Parzen Windows), while para approach assumes the data is from a known distribution.

I am not familiar with the parametric approach. Could anyone show me some well known algorithms?  By the way, if the MLE is a kind of parametric approach (the density curve is known, and then find the parameter corresponding to the maximum value)?

Comment: This is probably more suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MLE is by definition a parametric approach. You are estimating the parameters to a distribution, which maximizes the probability of observation of the data. Between, a non parametric approach generally means infinite number of parameters rather than an absence of parameters. For example a dirichlet process.

Comment: Please add some citations to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about a lot of terminology here.

Maximum likelihood makes sense for a paraemtric model (say a Gaussian distribution) because the number of parameters is fixed a priori and so it makes sense to ask what the 'best' estimates are. Maximum likelihood gives you one (of many) possible answers.

One way of understanding non-parametric methods is that the number of parameters they have grows as the number of samples increases. Thus a KDE has one parameter for each data point, plus a bandwidth parameter. What would MLE mean here? You increase the number of parameters as more data arrives, and thus there's no sense of best value for a fixed set of parameters.